# NHibernate count number of groups

Tags: c#, nhibernate, group-by, hql, queryover

I'm using NHibernate and I need to count the number of rows returned from a Group By.

It's important to mention that I have at least two columns in the group by statement. I'd like to avoid straight SQL since I have different databases. I'd really  like to send the command with either a MultiQuery or MultiCriteria since I have a lot of statistics I'd like to collect all at once (though not a requirement). I'd also like to avoid returning the list created by the Group By since it could be very large. I've tried multiple methods (HQL,QueryOver,Criteria). Unfortunately, nothing seems to work.

I have a table like this image: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcrJ7.png

[image]

I'd expect the query would look something like this

```
SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT * FROM Table t WHERE t.A = 1 GROUP BY t.B, t.C )
```

This particular query would return 3

Comment: The SQL you posted won't run (You can't select `t.A` in the inner query since it isn't part of the `group by` clause)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Linq` you could try something like this:

```
var result = from t in Table // <-- session.Query<Table>() to get queryable
             where t.A == 1
             group t by new { t.B, T.C } into g
             select g.Count();
```

Remember to add the namespace `NHibernate.Linq` in your cs file.